# ValueError: invalid syntax for integer with base 10 - Reading numbers from files in Micropython

Tags: string, type-conversion, integer, micropython

I am building a matrix display using LED strips which are now working. As part of that in the full version of Python I have a program which reads an image and then saves the RGB values of the pixels into a file one line at a time. The idea being that on my Pico I will read that file and use the data to set each pixel and rebuild the image.

I can read the file fine using the following:
Code: Select all

```
file1 = open('01b.txt', 'r')
count = 0
 
while True:
    count += 1
 
    # Get next line from file
    T = file1.readline(2)
    line = file1.readline(4)
    T = file1.readline(1) # Skip a comma after the number
    gl = file1.readline(3)
    T = file1.readline(1) # Skip a comma after the number
    rl = file1.readline(3)
    T = file1.readline(1) # Skip a comma after the number
    bl = file1.readline(3)
    # if line is empty
    # end of file is reached
    if not line:
        break
    print("1: "+line)
    print("2: "+rl)
    print("3: "+gl)
    print("4: "+bl)
    print("---------------------------------------") 
file1.close()
```

### This gives me an output as follows:
1: 0000
2: 002
3: 001
4: 003

Now I need to turn the values into integer numbers to pass to the LED strip so it can set the pixel but when I try to add the following I get the error in the title of this query, that being ValueError: invalid syntax for integer with base 10:
Code: Select all

```
lt = str(line)
    lt2 = int(lt)
```

What am I missing here and why can I not turn what is a string of 3 or 4 numbers into an actual number which I can then pass to the LED strip to set the pixel?

Comment: What is the contents of the file?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `readline()` instead of `read()`?

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]?  I think your only issue is knowing how to convert strings to integers so there is no need to discuss files, LEDs, and pixels.  What version of MicroPython are you using?  I tried to reproduce your problem on v1.22.0-preview by running `int("0000")` in a REPL but it returned 0 as expected.  It also works fine if there is white space at the end of the string.  You can run `print(repr(some_string))` to see exactly what's in your string.